# CSS of nested selector is not being applied to div

Tags: css, sass

I utilised the BEM method and my `<div>` is showing the css from the Block and Modifier, but not the Element

i.e. the css for `c-banner`(block) and `--warning`(modifier) is appearing but not `__icon`(element).

I know that the `color` of the modifier is appearing because I tried changing it to another `color` and it appears on the UI.

Eg:
Currently:

```css
&--warning {
  color: #D9822B
}
```

Edited:

```css
&--warning {
  color: black
}
```

Once changed, the icon of `--warning` will show up with a black color on the UI.

However, the `padding-right` of `__icon` doesn't ever get applied.

```css
c-banner {
/* Block CSS Properties */

  &__icon {
    padding-right: 12px;

    &--warning { /* Used for warning purposes */
      color: #D9822B;
    }

    &--primary { /* Used for general information */
      color: #137CBD;
    }

    &--success { /* Used for verified access */
      color: #0F9960;
    }

    &--danger { /* Used as a hard stop */
      color: #DB3737;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm genuinely perplexed as to why the `padding-right` of `__icon` does not get applied but the `color` of `--warning` is

Comment: Could you provide the html structure if you can?

Comment: It's `.jsx` but here you go


```jsx
        <div className="c-banner">
          <i className="material-icons c-banner__icon--warning">warning</i>
          You have {`${props.filesStatus.numberOfExtractingFiles}`} files that
          are still being processed in Uploads. As a result, your downloaded
          spreadsheet may not contain the most updated records.
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are missing is:
`.c-banner` ..... the dot before the classname

Also, for padding to work they have to be inside `--warning` because you are chaining to form the full selector and there is no selector that ends with `__icon`

You can style `material-icons` if you want to affect multiple:

```
.c-banner {

  .material-icons { padding-right: 12px; } 
  /* can also do [class*="__icon"] but may be less predictable */

  &__icon {
    /* rest of the scss */
  }
}
```

Comment: In that case, does that mean that I'll definitely have to define padding-right of 12px for each of the 4 different `--` modifiers?

Comment: You can style your `material-icons` class as it will be available on all icon class. See updated answer.